# IIS returning 404 when virtual directory has a specific name

Tags: windows-server-2016, iis-10, virtual-directory

IIS Version: 10.0.14393.0

OS: Windows Server 2016

I'm trying to access a virtual directory via IIS which is pointed to a folder that just contains a basic html page, however it's returning 404 and I'm not sure why. It seems to have to do with the specific name of the virtual directory, let's say ABC_ABC1234. At first I thought it was a folder permission issue, but I created a second virtual directory named Test, pointed it to the same folder, and the html page loads up just fine. The only difference between the two virtual directories is the name, and they are targeting the same app pool, folder, etc.

There are other virtual directories with the same naming convention and those all work. I also tried the same virtual directory name on another server, and it works just fine. I didn't see anything out of the ordinary in the event viewer logs or in the IIS logs. I compared the entries in the applicationHost.config file and they are identical except for the name. I've tried IIS resets, server restarts, deleting and recreating the virtual directory, all to no avail.

I am pretty much out of ideas at this point. Any help or suggestions on what would cause this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Read IIS log files to see what's the substatus code, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 You might hit request filtering.

Comment: It looks like it's returning 404.4 which is No Handler Configured. I don't see any difference in the handler mappings between ABC_ABC1234 and Test, both are set up to use url rewrite and reverse proxy, the .htm file extension does not appear in the request filtering for either. Anything I missed that I should try?

Comment: Please make sure permission on virtual directory allows the IIS User to access that folder, and did you try browsing the directory from within your IIS program or typing in the url of the directory manually in a browser?